# Discrete valuation on the local ring of a nonsingular curve

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra, valuation-theory

I have a question stemming from a line in Hartshorne's *Algebraic Geometry*, Section 1.6. I'll put the quote here:

> If $P$ is a point on a nonsingular curve $Y$, then by (5.1) the local ring $\mathcal{O}_p$ is a regular local ring of dimension one, and so by (6.2A) is is a discrete valuation ring. Its quotient field is the function field $K$ of $Y$, and since $k \subseteq \mathcal{O}_p$, it is a valuation ring of $K/k$.

My only question is how does the last line follow? Is it a general fact that a valuation of a quotient field $K$ obtained from an integral domain $R$ vanishes on any subfield of $R$? If so, where can I see a proof of that?

I've tried playing around with this and seem to be stuck, although I'm almost positive that the answer is right in front of me.

Comment: Combine the following: i) If $x$ is in $k$, then $v(x) \geq 0$. ii) $v(1/x) = -v(x)$.

Comment: I think I see it now. Thanks.